# mejorar la velocidad del count

Tags: python, csv, count

tengo el siguiente código el cual lee un archivo, los registros están repetido, así que en una lista meto todas incluyendo duplicados y hago un set para después compararlo con las lista y obtener el numero de veces que se repite, el detalle es que al escribirlo a un archivo tarda demasiado, son alrededor de 1M de registros.

```
import csv

with open(file, 'r') as act:
    lec = csv.reader(act, delimiter='|')
    reg  = [x[2] for x in lec]

sin_dups = list(set(reg))

salida = open('cuenta_cuentas.txt', 'w')

for x in sin_dups:
    if x in reg:
        registro = [x]
        rep = [str(reg.count(x))]
        data = registro + rep
        salida.write(','.join(data) + '\n')

salida.close()
```

en si, debería devolverme uno 500k registros con el numero de veces que se repite, pero el proceso demora demasiado.

Comment: ¿Vienen ordenados los datos? ¿Qué tipo de dato es `x[2]` (entero, string, fecha, ...)? ¿Qué rango de valores tiene?

Comment: @CandidMoe, una disculpa por no haber visto tú comentario y respuesta, ya añadí una posible solución.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que haces es horriblemente ineficiente: creas una lista de un millón de elementos, luego la conviertes en un set y de vuelta en lista, para recorrerla una vez más generando la salida. Son como 4 millones de accesos.

La forma normal de eliminar duplicados es ordenar el archivo en forma externa. Un utilitario de sort externo siempre será más rápido y eficiente.

El programa recibe el archivo donde los duplicados vienen en un solo bloque, por lo que contarlos y reducirlos es trivial.

En este algoritmo, el archivo se procesa en una sola pasada, sin requerir almacenar nada en memoria:

```
with open("sorted.csv", 'r') as act:
    with open('cuenta_cuentas.txt', 'w') as salida:
        prev = None
        rep = 0
        for registro in csv.reader(act, delimiter='|'):
            if registro[2] != prev: 
                if rep:
                    salida.write(f"{prev},{rep}\n")
                prev = registro[2]
                rep = 1
            else:
                rep += 1
        if rep:
            salida.write(f"{prev},{rep}\n")
```

La variable `prev` nos da la llave del registro anterior, mientras que `registro[2]` es la llave del registro actual. La variable `rep` lleva la cuenta de cuantas veces se repite la llave.

Tras leer un registro, comparamos su llave contra la anterior. Si son iguales, simplemente agrega 1 al contador `rep`. Si son distintas, se ha producido un cambio de llave y podemos imprimir sus datos (llave y cuenta) y reinicializar `prev` con la llave actual y poner `rep` en 1.

Al terminar de leer el archivo de entrada, todavía queda una llave por imprimir, junto con su cuenta.

#### Demo

*sorted.csv*

```
reg1|ABC|0001|+45
reg2|ABC|0001|-12
reg3|XYZ|0001|+5
reg4|OLL|0002|+40
reg5|HHH|0003|+5
reg6|HUY|0003|+1
```

produce:

*cuenta_cuentas.txt*

```
0001,3
0002,1
0003,2
```

Answer (score 0):

2 días después de mi pregunta encontré un posible solución con el modulo Counter, reduce el proceso a menos de la mitad, anteriormente el proceso con aproximadamente 1M de registros demoraba de 5 a 8 min y ahora tarda de 1 a 2 minutos.

Aquí mi posible solución.

```
import collections
from collections import Counter
import csv

with open(file, 'r') as act:
    lec = csv.reader(act, delimiter='|')
    reg = [n[2] for n in lec]

contador = Counter()
contador.update(reg)
# mas_rep es una lista[reg,frecuencia_reg]
mas_rep = contador.most_common()

for e in mas_rep:
    salida.write('{},{}'.format(e[0],e[1]))

salida.close()
```

devolviendo los registros de mayor a menor según su frecuencia:

```
10121021452,32
12021352152,31
```

el archivo de donde obtengo los datos son cadenas de texto delimitadas por '|', durante el proceso de trabajo y en su resultado debo obtener los resultados de manera idéntica sin cambiar su tipo de dato.